# Other optimal or better ways of referencing 2D arrays to a function and comma separated statements in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int string_length(int (*s)[10], int L, int W)
{
  int len = 0;
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < W; j++)
    {
      len++;
      printf("%d ", *(*(s + i) + j));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return len;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int str[20][10] =
  {
    { 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } 
  };

  printf("the sizeof this 2d array will be %lu \n", sizeof(str));
  printf("the length of the strings will be %lu \n",
      sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]));
  printf("the width of the each string %lu \n",
      sizeof(str[0]) / sizeof(str[0][0]));
  printf("the result is %d \n",
      string_length(str, sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]),
          sizeof(str[0]) / sizeof(str[0][0])));

  int i = 0;
  while (i < 10)
    printf("hello %d\n", i), i++;

  return 0;
}
```

this is one method I figured out doing the referencing via address I know there are many other ways ,Can anyone list out the other methods how 2D referencing can be done effectively ?? and my code is a bit shabby so can anyone suggest the other ways how it can be done.And how does the comma separated statements work in the second while loop??? how the compiler deals with these statements is there any special cases.

Comment: Have you been in a hurry?

Comment: I just wanted to determine the length without passing it to the module tried with (*s)[10] and then s[20][10] and **s but the loops did not even proceed the len was returned as 0 so ended up in this so are there anyother methods.@dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone list out the other methods how 2D referencing can be done effectively?

The simplest thing is to replace an exercise in pointer arithmetic `*(*(s+i)+j)` with the more conventional `s[i][j]`:

```
for(i=0;i<L;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<W;j++) {
        len++;
        printf("%d ", s[i][j]); <<== Here
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

[Demo of this change on ideone](http://ideone.com/2daY2M) produces identical output with your original program ([here](http://ideone.com/g40lJy)).

> And how does the comma separated statements work in the second while loop?

[Comma is a standard C operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator); it acts as a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

To allow for passing arrays of variable size int `string_length`, you can change the structure of the array for an array of pointers, like this:

```
int string_length(int **s,int L,int W) {
    ... // This code does not change from the above
}
int *str[5]={
    (int[]){2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    (int[]){2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    (int[]){2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    (int[]){2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    (int[]){2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};
printf("the result is %d \n",string_length(str, 5, 10));
```

One consequence of this choice is that the row-sizing macro would no longer work ([see a demo here](http://ideone.com/E8i4Xr)); array-sizing macro (i.e. the one determining the number of rows) would continue working, though. Another consequence is that you would not longer be able to declare more items than you put in the initializer, because the rest would be set to `NULL` pointers, breaking the printing loop.

Comment: thanks @dasblinkenlight other ways of passing 2D array to a function
why does the string_length(int** s) here and string_length(int (*s)[10]) is not working,these ways produce wrong results.Is this the way or rule of passing it.

Comment: @Krishnasundar Take a look at the edit, it shows how you can initialize an array of pointers.